# Update version of tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat7, centos7

I have installed tomcat 7.0.76 using this repo:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
```

I did like this:

```
yum install -y tomcat tomcat-webapps tomcat-admin-webapps
```

I need to update to the last version 7.0.90 but the next command:

`yum update tomcat` show this:

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

- base: mirror.tedra.es
- extras: mirror.tedra.es
- updates: mirror.airenetworks.es

No packages marked for update

Which are the steps??. Do I need to remove the actual version and install it manually??.

All the links I have seen are about install a new version

**UPDATE 1:**

I have installed the distro in /opt/tomcat7-90. Stopped the service using /bin/shutdown.sh and then ./startup.sh and it seems work.

The problem is I have two server with differents configurations and in one of them it doesn't find java.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are a little new to linux and how distributions work. linux distros especially RHLE and its derivatives are not so fast in updating their packages.

Comment: In general if you want to stick to the latest version of a specific software, you need to learn how to compile that piece of software yourself. You can take a look into switching to Arch and/or Gentoo distros as well. They are much more fast paced.